# Error : expected 'uint8_t *' but argument is of type 'char *'

Tags: c, avr

I am using Avr Studio 5, how can I solve this error:

```
Error   6   expected 'uint8_t *' but argument is of type 'char *'   C:\Users\RC\Documents\AVRStudio\lcd\lcd\lcd.c   65  6   lcd
```

Relevant code:

```
     void Lcd_4bit_String(uint8_t *Lcd_Str)
     {
        while(Lcd_Str != '\0')
        Lcd_4bit_Data(*Lcd_Str++);
     }
```

Comment: Your problem seems to be at the site where you /call/ the function `Lcd_4bit_String`. Can you please include that code?

Comment: Also, the `while` condition seems fishy - shouldn't it be `while(*Lcd_Str != '\0')`? (with the `*` before `Lcd_Str`)

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is to simply cast the argument when you call it:

```
char myMessage[] = "Hello world";
Lcd_4bit_String((uint8_t *)myMessage);
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your error, The Function is expecting `uint8_t *`, but you are passing `char *`(That is string).
Before Passing string to your function typecast it to `uint8_t *` and pass it. then this function will work.
Example:

```
Lcd_4bit_String((uint8_t *)string); // call your function like this.

void Lcd_4bit_String(uint8_t *Lcd_Str)
 {
    while(Lcd_Str != '\0')
    Lcd_4bit_Data(*Lcd_Str++);
 }
```

Comment: Lcd_4bit_Data() probably takes an uint8_t type.

Comment: @this ok. i will change that